# password protect individual pages

Tags: login, password

Is it possible to password protect individual pages with Wordpress? What I'm trying to do is have special pages suche as somesite.com/project1 which has a username and password that I can set, but somesite.com/project2 has a different username and password.

And so on and so forth, with new usernames and passwords for new pages created down the line.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can password protect individual pages and posts.  Under the Publish section of the dashboard, look under the link for **VISIBILITY**. The default setting is PUBLIC, but you can change it to PRIVATE, which only you can see when you're logged in, or PASSWORD PROTECTED, which requires you to enter a password when you are posting the page/post, and for the reader to enter the password to view the content.  Using this method, there is no username but you can control visibility

An alternative would be to use a membership plugin, which requires an individual user to log in, where you control their access to areas of your blog/site and what documents they have access.

[Link to Membership Plugins in the Codex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=membership&sort=)

Comment: I was looking for this all day and it was so easy to fix! Thanks :)

Comment: @Nick  - Glad it worked for you

Comment: For those who want to where it is, this option is available in dashboard->Posts->during editing a particular post.